# Change the role delimiter in GeoServer when using HTTP header attribute in security

Tags: geoserver

According to [docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/usergrouprole/rolesource.html), when using an HTTP header attribute for security:

> The **default** syntax is:
>
> - roles are delimited by `;`
> - a role parameter list starts with `(` and ends with `)`
> - a role parameter is a key value pair delimited by `=`
> - role parameters are delimited by `,`

So if there's a default, that means there is an option. How can I change the delimiters? I'd like roles to be delimited by comma, and role parameters to be delimited by semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

From a look at the code, it seems to be technically possible (by calling the [`setRoleParameterDelimiterString`](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/bb1d1b8426ddae4eec16bc8289bdeed9fd0c2f4c/src/main/src/main/java/org/geoserver/security/impl/GeoServerRoleConverterImpl.java#LL53C17-L53C48) method in `GeoServerRoleConverterImpl` but there don't seem to be any calls in the code base to that method.

Looks like you will need to enhance the GUI somewhere to make this (and the other setters in the class) available to the user, you might also need to make some other changes to make sure the values are persisted too.